# Generate random numbers on input fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, random, input

I'm building a little app for my kid.  Sort of a real simple D&D thing.  I'm wondering if there is a way to generate a random number as an input field.  Something like:

```
f.text_field :health = rand(1-20) + 20
```

I could do it in the controller and just have it display but I'd like to have it as an input field if that is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do it easily, actually you have not given controller code but I just take one example share you how to do it. In you controller action method of new you can add following

```
    @user = User.new
    @random = rand(1-20) + 20
```

You have define `@random` for random string to be put in your view file. Now in your form which ever field you have just put following to add value, I am providing your here sample username

```
<%= text_field_tag(:username, nil, value: @random) %>
```

In your field add just `value: @random` it will put your random value their.

Comment: This is perfect.  Thank you.  I had thought about adding that to the controller but was uncertain as how to get that into the form and this makes perfect sense.